# SQL query for fetching rows with their id mentioned in a column of that same row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get those rows whose Id's I have described in a column of that same table . Here's the data:

```
id    layer    sublayer
1     A        2, 3, 4
2     B        5
3     C        NULL
4     D        NULL
5     E        NULL
```

Here's what I am trying to do.
For layer A ,I want to fetch B,C,D whose id's are described in the column sublayer . Here id is the primary key.Is it possible to read individual values from a column separated with special characters ?

Comment: mySQL supports a [SET data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) which has a function `FIND_IN_SET` which may do what you're after

Comment: what is your goal? do you want 2 columns: row1: `A`  `B,C,D`  row2:   `B`  `E`

Comment: Your table is not normalized, you better make a new table for sublayer, and then put the sub layer id (or something like that) in the sublayer column, that would make things much easier.

Comment: That's interesting .Thnks @xQbert

Comment: No I want 3 rows 2,3,4 @NayruLove

Answer (score 3):

Using [Find_In_set function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)  for [set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) datatypes in conjunction with group_concat (cross join may not be needed but I like it for the fact it calculates the set once instead of for each row..)

I'm using group concat to bring all the rows into one large data set so we can simply check for the existence of the ID.  However, I'm not sure how well group_concat will work with a set datatype already having a , separated values...

On a large data set I would be concerned about performance. Your best bet long term is to normalize the data.  But if that's not an option...

[Working SQL Fiddle:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e70f/3/0)

```
SELECT * 
FROM layer
CROSS JOIN (SELECT group_Concat(sublayer separator ',') v FROM layer) myset
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, myset.v) > 0;
```

Comment: This kind of stuff gives me nightmares. I feel like  Donald Sutherland in Invasion of the Bodysnatchers

Comment: @Strawberry +1 This is some epic query. Need to dig deeper. Thanks for sharing xQbert

Comment: That is what I want .Thnks @xQbert

Comment: @strawberry  I didn't condone this as being the "RIGHT" thing to do.  Normalizing the data is the RIGHT thing to do. However, this should address the specific question without beating someone up about a poor design they may not be able to change.

Comment: If you offer a solution, then by implication, you condone that solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
SELECT * 
FROM layer
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID,(
      select sublayer from table where layer='A'))>1
```

Comment: >1 would omit if a match occurred within the first position of the set.  eg.  Find_in_SET(1,1,2,3,4) > 1 would return false.